# Import .kml into .osm file

Tags: merge, kml, openstreetmap

I have a pretty big .kml file (it is the property of my company, and I can legally use it), what I want to import into an .osm file, downloaded from download.geofabrik.de. I can open this .osm map in softwares, for completely offline usage, such as Marble.

My question is: can I somehow merge this kml and osm file, so when I open the merged file in Marble, the routes described by the kml are also visible? So basically, I want to merge a.kml with b.osm, resulting in c.osm, what I can use offline.

Is it possible? If yes, can you direct me in the right direction?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Some notes:

- I have tried GPSBabel, it indicates that it can convert .kml to .osm. It generates a 65MB .osm file from my 12MB .kml, but when I open it in Marble, it does not show any routes, so it looks like a dead end. :/
- The weird thing is, GPSBabel produced an input what QGIS could open. I merged the two .osm file with osmosis, but the problem is, the output is invalid, nothing can open it.
- JOSM does not open the original .osm file, what is 1GB of size.

ps: I have posted this on help.openstreetmap.org as well, but for now, nobody could help me, so I am trying to get some answer here, maybe... Sorry for the "repost", and thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Have you tried opening the two .osm files in JOSM and merging the two data layers there?

Comment: Nop, I gonna give it a try, will reply with the result!

Comment: Unfortunately, JOSM does not open the original .osm file. It is the map of Hungary, what is 1GB in uncompressed format, and 80MB or so compressed. :/

Comment: Gosh, I could have guessed that.
But another thing: are you sure you need a combined `.osm` file in your software (“for offline usage” as you say)? In general, `.osm` is more a low level raw data exchange format, rather than something for consumer applications…

Comment: As dumb as it is, it is what the company wants, so the decision is out of my hands at the moment. If not possible, I will try to force it so the osm and kml files remain separate (which is much more logical imo).

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is honestly the wrong way to go about it, but still possible.

The first step is to use [ogr2osm](https://github.com/pnorman/ogr2osm) with the command-line flags `--positive-id`, `--add-version`, --add-timestamp`and with`--id 3000000000` (or some other number larger than the largest node ID in the file.

You will then have a .osm file that [Osmosis](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis) or [Osmconvert](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmconvert) can merge with another file, in this case your downloaded software. In the case of osmosis, `osmosis --read-xml internal.osm --sort --read-xml extract.osm --sort --merge --write-xml combined.osm` *(untested)*

A more common way would be to download the shapefiles for the region from geofabrik then use ogr2ogr and similar tools to combine them with the .kml file in the output format of your choice.

Keep in mind that if you distribute this "derivative database" you have created, it has to be licensed under the ODbL. This does not apply if you're distributing it internally only.